# C# Ejercicio programación concurrente [Matriz => sacar dos Listas<positivos y negativos>]

Tags: c#, hilos, matrices

Dada una matriz de números enteros rectangular, calcular de forma paralela dos listas: una con los
valores positivos y otra con los valores negativos. Lo que llevo hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
class Worker
{
    private int[,] A;
    private int índiceDesde, índiceHasta;
    private List<int> listaN, listaP;

    /// <summary>
    /// Trabajor encargado de sacar las listas Positivas y Negativas de la matriz A dejándolas sobre la listaP y la listaN
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="índiceDesde"></param>
    /// <param name="índiceHasta"></param>
    /// <param name="A">Matriz a valorar</param>
    /// <param name="listaP">Lista de numeros Positivos</param>
    /// <param name="listaN">Lista de numeros Negativos</param>
    internal Worker(int índiceDesde, int índiceHasta, int[,] A, ref List<int> listaP, ref List<int> listaN)
    {
        this.A = A;
        this.índiceDesde = índiceDesde;
        this.índiceHasta = índiceHasta;
        this.listaP = listaP;
        this.listaN = listaN;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Metodo que calcula Las listas positivas y negativas de la matiz A
    /// </summary>
    internal void Calcular()
    {
        int contador = 0;
        for (int k = this.índiceDesde; k < this.índiceHasta; k++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < A.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < A.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (A[i, j] < 0)
                    {
                        listaN.Add(A[i, j]);
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        listaP.Add(A[i, j]);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Clase Master:*

```
class Master
{
    private int[,] matrizA; 
    private int numeroHilos;
    private List<int> listaN, listaP;

    public Master(int[,] matrizA, ref List<int> listaP, ref List<int> listaN, int posPorHilos)
    {
        this.matrizA = matrizA;
        this.numeroHilos = numHilos(matrizA, posPorHilos);
        this.listaN = listaN;
        this.listaP = listaP;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Método Auxiliar (opcional)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="matrizA"></param>
    /// <param name="posPorHilos"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private int numHilos(int[,] matrizA, int posPorHilos)
    {
        return (matrizA.Length / posPorHilos) / 2;
    }

    public void Calcular()
    {
        //REservamos espacio para el array de trabajadores
        Worker[] workers = new Worker[numeroHilos];
        int elementosPorHilo = this.matrizA.Length / numeroHilos;
        for (short i = 0; i < numeroHilos; i++)
            workers[i] = new Worker(i * elementosPorHilo,
                (i < this.numeroHilos - 1) ? (i + 1) * elementosPorHilo - 1 : this.matrizA.Length - 1,
                matrizA,ref listaP,ref listaN);

        //Creamos y lanzamos los hilos trabajadores
        Thread[] hilos = new Thread[workers.Length];
        for (short i = 0; i < hilos.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            hilos[i] = new Thread(workers[i].Calcular);
            hilos[i].Name = "Worker Matriz ListaPositivos y Lista Negativos  " + (i);
            hilos[i].Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;
            hilos[i].Start();
        }
        //Esperamos por la finalización de los hilos trabajadores.
        foreach (Thread hilo in hilos)
            hilo.Join();
    }
}
```

*Clase Program:*

```
public class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] A = CrearMatrizAleatoria(4, 5, -10, 10);
        List<int> lista1, lista2;
        int numeroHilos = 5;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Matriz A");
        mostrarMatriz(A);

        // Ejercicio 1. 
        ejercicio1(A, out lista1, out lista2, 4); //Modificar la signatura del método ejercicio1 para que reciba como parámetro las partes en que se dividirá A
        System.Console.WriteLine("Ejercicio1. Calcula Listas sin TPL y con nPartes hilos");
        mostrar(lista1); mostrar(lista2);

    }
    //
    // Ejercicio1
    // Versión paralela sin TPL y numeroHilos = nPartes
    //
    public static void ejercicio1(int[,] A, out List<int> lista1, out List<int> lista2, int numeroHilos)
    {
        lista1 = null; lista2 = null;
        //List<int> listaN = null;
        //List<int> listaP = null;
        //int numeroHilos = 0;
        //mostrarMatriz(A);

        ///CODIGO
        List<int> listaN = null;
        List<int> listaP = null;
        System.Console.WriteLine("\tMatriz Original\n");
        mostrarMatriz(A);


        Master master = new Master(A, ref lista1, ref lista2, numeroHilos);
        master.Calcular();
    }
    public static int[,] CrearMatrizAleatoria(int filas, int columnas, int menor, int mayor) {
        int[,] vector = new int[filas, columnas];
        Random random = new Random(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
               vector[i,j] = (int)random.Next(menor, mayor + 1);
        return vector;
    }

    public static void mostrarMatriz(int [,] matriz)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
                System.Console.Write(matriz[i,j]+" ");
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    public static void mostrar<T>(IEnumerable<T> lista)
    {
        foreach (T x in lista) {
            Console.Write(x + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
}
```

El programa al ejecutarlo "casca", me da error en la clase Worker a la altura de:

```
listaN.Add(A[i, j]);
```

Aunque creo que no debe ser lo único que tengo mal, necesitaría algo de ayuda y orientación, gracias.

*Me aparece el siguiente error al compilar:*

> Excepción no controlada:
>   Excepción no controlada: System.NullReferenceExcepti
>   stablecida como instancia de un objeto.
>      en Matriz.Worker.Calcular() en C:\Users\powerserv
>   CURSO\Segundo Semestre\TPP\Exe
>      en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Cont
>      en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(
>   ntext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boole
>      en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Executio
>   ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean prese
>      en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Executio
>   ontextCallback callback, Object state)
>      en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>   System.NullReferenceException: Referencia a objeto n
>    de un objeto.
>      en Matriz.Worker.Calcular() en C:\Users\powerserv
>   CURSO\Segundo Semestre\TPP\Exe
>      en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Cont
>      en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(
>   ntext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boole
>      en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Executio
>   ontextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean prese
>      en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(Executio
>   ontextCallback callback, Object state)
>      en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: "casca" no es una buena descripción del error. Deberías copiar y pegar la excepción exacta que te está lanzando para que puedas recibir ayuda.

Comment: Podrías compartirnos tu mensaje de error? Puedes decirnos de qué manera se "Casca"?

Comment: Aparte porqué usas "Thread"? eso es del pleistoceno. De hecho el código que tienes es bastante rebuscado, busca información sobre Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: He vuelto a crear el programa desde cero, modificando la clase Program, y ya  he conseguido la solución. Gracias por la ayuda y si tiene alguien curiosidad por como lo he hecho, a continuación os dejo el resultado:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí va el código del programa ya corregido por si a alguien le interesa:

Clase Worker:

```
internal class WorkerMatriz
{
    private int[,] matriz;

    private int indiceDesde, indiceHasta;

    private List<int> resultadoP;
    private List<int> resultadoN;

    internal WorkerMatriz(int indiceDesde, int indiceHasta, int[,] matriz, ref List<int> resultadoP, ref List<int> resultadoN)
    {
        this.indiceDesde = indiceDesde;
        this.indiceHasta = indiceHasta;
        this.matriz = matriz;
        this.resultadoP = resultadoP;
        this.resultadoN = resultadoN;
    }

    internal void Espejo()
    {
        int matACols = matriz.GetLength(1);
        int matARows = matriz.GetLength(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < matARows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matACols; j++)
            {
                if (matriz[i, j] > 0)
                    resultadoP.Add(matriz[i, j]);
                else
                {
                    resultadoN.Add(matriz[i, j]);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Clase Master:

```
 class MasterMatriz
{
    int[,] matriz;
    int numeroHilos;
    List<int> resultadoP;
    List<int> resultadoN;

    public MasterMatriz(int[,] matriz, List<int> resultadoP, List<int> resultadoN, int posPorHilos)
    {
        this.matriz = matriz;
        this.resultadoP = resultadoP;
        this.resultadoN = resultadoN;
        this.numeroHilos = numHilos(matriz, posPorHilos);
    }

    /// Posible opcion de posicion por hilos ///


    //public Master(short[] vector, ref short[] resultado, int posPorHilos)
    //{
    //    this.vector = vector;
    //    this.resultado = resultado;
    //    this.numeroHilos = numHilos(vector, posPorHilos);
    //}
    /// <summary>
    /// Metodo auxiliar
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="vector"></param>
    /// <param name="posPorHilo"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    int numHilos(int[,] matriz, int posPorHilo)
    {
        return (matriz.Length / posPorHilo) / 2;
    }

    public void CalcularEspejo()
    {
        WorkerMatriz[] workers = new WorkerMatriz[this.numeroHilos];
        int elementosPorHilo = this.matriz.Length / numeroHilos;
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroHilos; i++)
        {
            workers[i] = new WorkerMatriz(i * elementosPorHilo,
                (i < this.numeroHilos - 1) ? (i + 1) * elementosPorHilo - 1 : this.matriz.Length - 1,// último
                matriz, ref resultadoP, ref resultadoN);
        }
        Thread[] hilos = new Thread[numeroHilos];
        for(int i=0; i<numeroHilos; i++)
        {
            hilos[i] = new Thread(workers[i].Espejo);
            hilos[i].Name = "Worker Vectores " + (i + 1);  // nos llamamos entonces (opcional)
            hilos[i].Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal;  // les asignamos una prioridad (opcional)
            hilos[i].Start();
        }
        for(int i= 0; i < hilos.Length; i++)
        {
            hilos[i].Join();
        }
        }
    }
```

Clase Program:

```
public class ProgramaMatriz {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Ejemplo1
        int[,] A = CrearMatrizAleatoria(4, 5, -10, 10);
        int PosPorHiloA = 5;
        System.Console.WriteLine("Matriz A");
        mostrarMatriz(A);



        // Ejercicio 1. 
        System.Console.WriteLine("Ejercicio1. Espejo de un vector sin TPL");
        ejercicio1(A, PosPorHiloA);


    }


    //
    // Ejercicio1
    // Versión paralela del cálculo del espejo de un vector sin TPL.
    //
    public static void ejercicio1(int [,]A, int PosPorHiloA)
    {
        ejercicio1tucodigo(A, PosPorHiloA);


    }
    public static void ejercicio1tucodigo(int [,]matriz, int PosPorHilo) 
    {
      List<int> resultadoP = null;
      List<int> resultadoN = null;
      System.Console.WriteLine("Matriz Original");
      mostrarMatriz<int>(matriz);

        //Aqui va tu codigo
        resultadoP = new List<int>(matriz.GetLength(0));
        resultadoN = new List<int>(matriz.GetLength(0));
        MasterMatriz master = new MasterMatriz(matriz,  resultadoP, resultadoN, PosPorHilo);
        master.CalcularEspejo();


      System.Console.WriteLine("\nVector resultado negativos");
      mostrar<int>(resultadoN);
        System.Console.WriteLine("\nVector resultado positivos");
        mostrar<int>(resultadoP);
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }



    public static void mostrarVector<T>(T[] matriz)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
                System.Console.Write(matriz[i] + " ");

        }
    }
    public static void mostrarMatriz<T>(T[,] matriz)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                System.Console.Write(matriz[i, j] + " ");
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine();

        }
    }
    public static int[,] CrearMatrizAleatoria(int filas, int columnas, int menor, int mayor)
    {
        int[,] vector = new int[filas, columnas];
        Random random = new Random(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++)
                vector[i, j] = (int)random.Next(menor, mayor + 1);
        return vector;
    }


    public static void mostrar<T>(IEnumerable<T> lista)
    {
        foreach (T x in lista)
        {
            Console.Write(x + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Resultado:

Matriz A
-5 -8 -1 6 3
-1 -3 9 -8 3
-10 -5 -4 10 4
3 -5 2 4 4
Ejercicio1. 
Matriz Original
-5 -8 -1 6 3
-1 -3 9 -8 3
-10 -5 -4 10 4
3 -5 2 4 4

Vector resultado negativos
-5 -8 -1 -1 -3 -8 -10 -5 -4 -5 -5 -8 -1 -1 -3 -8 -10 -5 -4 -5

Vector resultado positivos
6 3 9 3 10 4 3 2 4 4 6 3 9 3 10 4 3 2 4 4

Presione una tecla para continuar . . .

Saludos!